# Powershell error trying to create a text file

Tags: powershell

```
Sub CreateAfile
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True)
    a.WriteLine("This is a test.")
    a.Close
End Sub
```

While trying to run above code in Powershell I am getting "Missing expression after ','".  Thanks

Comment: That is not PowerShell code. That is VBA?

Comment: The code run's fine as `.vbs`. Depending on rights, you may not be allowed to write to the root of the system drive.

Comment: A PowerShell equivalent for this VBScript could be `Add-Content -Path "c:\testfile.txt" -Value "This is a test."`

Answer (score 0):

That's not really `PowerShell`, it's `VB Script`.

Creating a file in PowerShell is as easy as:

```
New-Item -Name "myFile.txt" -ItemType File -Path "C:\temp"
```